# In a Vue app, Key Up Event fired on an input element when tabbed into. Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, data-binding, keyboard-events

Here is the HTML code,

```
<div id="vue-app">
       <h1>data binding</h1>
       <label>Name:</label>
       <input type="text" v-on:keyup="logName" />
    
       <label>Age:</label>
       <input type="text" v-on:keyup="logAge" />
    
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',

    methods: {
       logName: function() {
          console.log("You entered your name");
       },

       logAge: function() {
           console.log("You entered your age");
       }
    }
});
```

Now when I tab into the "Age" input field, it fires the "keyup" event. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tab is a key that fires the `v-on:keyup` event, use `v-on:input` event instead of it :

```
<div id="vue-app">
       <h1>data binding</h1>
       <label>Name:</label>
       <input type="text" v-on:input="logName" />
    
       <label>Age:</label>
       <input type="text" v-on:input="logAge" />
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour, since any key press trigger a keyup event. To prevent tab key from triggering this event you could try:

```
methods: {
       logName(e) {
          if(e.keyCode === 9) return
          console.log("You entered your name");
       },
       logAge(e) {
           if(e.keyCode === 9) return
           console.log("You entered your age");
       }
    }
```